# Trying to understand preoprocessor definition on windows CL.exe

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

good afternoon.

I'am current trying to compile a program linking to libCURL in windows, using MSVC, the current code is show below.

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB 
#include <curl/curl.h> 

int main() {  
   
 // INITIALIZATION //  
 curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);  
 curl_global_cleanup();  
 return 0;
}
```

While trying to static link, i **NEED** to define **CURL_STATICLIB**, else he tries to link to a DLL/so.

While compiling this code, i add an `/D CURL_STATICLIB=1`, which should prevent the needed to add the definition in code, but it makes no difference at all.

Am i understanding or doing something wrong?

cl.exe "/I" "path_to_libcurl_include" "/D CURL_STATICLIB=1" "/c" main.c

cl.exe main.OBJ path_to_libcurl

Either with or without =1 makes no difference.

[/D source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Too heavy on the double-quotes, you only need them for files whose path name contains an embedded space.  There are rather a lot of basic hello-world mistakes that are avoided when you use the IDE.  If not to use it permanently then to copy-paste the compile command.  The debug build in particular can diagnose a lot of UB, not something you'd want to throw away in C.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that i need to either:

Remove the space:

`cl.exe "/I" "path_to_libcurl_include" "/DCURL_STATICLIB=1" "/c" main.c`

Or remove the double quotes:

`cl.exe  /D  CURL_STATICLIB=1`

`cl.exe  /DCURL_STATICLIB=1`

Comment: You can drop the `=1` part, too. The equivalent of the code `#define` is just `/D CURL_STATICLIB`.